# SBT Won´t update .classpath in a Play Scala project

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

I am creating a new Play Scala project within Eclipse + Scala IDE.

The original build.sbt file is:

```
name := """portal"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws
)
```

I've edited it to include some more dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.1.0" % "test"
)
```

I can't figure out why SBT won't include Ebean, postgresql, nor scalatest in my classpath. Any help?

Comment: did you run `sbt eclipse`? I assume you mean the `.classpath` file eclipse uses.

Comment: I don't use sbt directly. I use activator. According to my understanding, it should download the dependencies and update eclipse's classpath just like it does in a Java/Play application. In this Scala/Play app, it is not working.

Comment: well, do use sbt directly. I'm not sure activator does/should do that for you.

Comment: activator is built on top of sbt. And this does work in a Play/Java project, but it doesn't in a Play/Scala project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened that I needed to run the command

```
activator eclipse
```

again, and refresh the IDE.